# Copy Edit:/ waveform to Sim:/ waveform in Modelsim

Tags: modelsim

I've loaded my waveforms from a previous simulation by going to File -> Load -> Macro File -> "wave.do". This causes the waveforms to be displayed next to blank simulation waveforms (see below). I would like to use my previously saved waveforms to resimulate.

[image: simulation waveforms]

I've tried right-clicking on an Edit:/ waveform and going to Edit -> Map to design signal -> and then entering the name of the corresponding design signal (e.g. sim:/majority3/x1) but this does not achieve the desired result.

I've also tried simply copying the Edit:/ waveform and pasting it to the Sim:/ waveform, but that didn't work either.

Any comments, suggestions, etc. are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run the wave.do from the modelsim command line (Transcript window).

[image]

I usually have script that runs all these setup operations for me (simulation, waveform window reloading and running):

```
vsim -t 1ps design_tb

restart -f -nowave    
do wave.do

run 200 us
```